# How do I exclude entries from a recursive CTE?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I exclude entries from a recursive CTW with Sqlite?

```
CREATE TABLE GroupMembers (
    group_id        VARCHAR,
    member_id       VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO GroupMembers(group_id, member_id) VALUES
    ('1', '10'),
    ('1', '20'),
    ('1', '30'),
    ('1', '-50'),
    ('2', '30'),
    ('2', '40'),
    ('3', '1'),
    ('3', '50'),
    ('4', '-10'),
    ('10', '50'),
    ('10', '60');
```

I want a query that will give me the list of members (recursively) in the group. However, a member with the first character being '-' means that the id that comes after the minus is NOT in the group.

For example, the members of '1' are '10', '20', '30', and '-50'. '10', however, is a group so we need to add its children '50' and '60'. However, '-50' is already a member so we cannot include '50'. In conclusion the members of '1' are '10', '20', '30', '-50', and '60'.

It seems like this query should work:

```
WITH RECURSIVE members(id) AS (
    VALUES('1')
    UNION
    SELECT gm.member_id 
        FROM members m
        INNER JOIN GroupMembers gm ON mg.group_id=m.id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN members e ON '-' || gm.member_id=e.id
        WHERE e.id IS NULL
)
SELECT id FROM members;
```

But I get the error: `multiple references to recursive table: members`

How can I fix/rewrite this to do what I want?

Note: it doesnt matter whether the '-50' entry is returned in the result set.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to get from this, but what's from with `WHERE substr(gm.member_id, 1, 1) <> '-'`

Comment: @Serpiton I updated the question, does that make it more clear?

Comment: Write one recursive CTE to get all included members ignoring `-`, write another recursive CTE to get all explicitly excluded members, then it's just `SELECT * FROM CTE1 EXCEPT SELECT * FROM CTE2`?

Comment: Just a note - part of the purpose of a database is to separate concepts so that they can be easily queried. You've mashed two concepts together - an identifier (50) and "belongingness" (-). If you have any control of this database, you should separate those concepts into their own columns. It would greatly enhance the meaning ("-50" looks like a negative number) and the efficiency (pulling strings apart is *extremely* expensive and scales very badly).

Comment: @hvd I added the '3' group to the groups. that group SHOULD contain '50' because it is included before the exclusion. Does that make sense?

Comment: @hvd yea at the end of the query i throw away all entries which start with '-'

Comment: @chacham15 Ah, right, I had missed that in your question.

Comment: Thanks, now I can see the logic that you are trying to query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a SQLite available for testing, but assuming the `-50` also means that `50` should be excluded as well, I think you are looking for this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE members(id) AS (
    VALUES('1')
    UNION
    SELECT gm.member_id 
    FROM GroupMembers gm 
      JOIN members m ON gm.group_id=m.id
    WHERE member_id not like '-%'
      AND not exists (select 1 
                      from groupMembers g2
                      where g2.member_id = '-'||gm.member_id)
)
SELECT id 
FROM members;
```

(The above works in Postgres)

You usually select from the base table in the recursive part and the join back to the actual CTE. The filtering of unwanted rows is then done with a regular `where` clause not by joining the CTE again. A recursive CTE is defined to terminate when the JOIN finds no more rows.

SQLFiddle (Postgres): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/04405/1

**Edit** after the requirements have changed (have been detailed):

As you need to exclude the rows based on their position (a detail that you didn't provide in your original question). The filter can only be done *outside* of the CTE. Again I can't test this with SQLite, only with Postgres:

```
WITH RECURSIVE members(id, level) AS (
    VALUES('4', 1)
    UNION
    SELECT gm.member_id, m.level + 1
    FROM GroupMembers gm 
      JOIN members m ON gm.group_id=m.id
)
SELECT m.id, m.level
FROM members m
where id not like '-%'
  and not exists (select 1 
                  from members m2
                  where m2.level < m.level 
                    and m2.id = '-'||m.id);
```

Updated SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ec0f9/3